# HTML5 audio controls overflowing in Safari Mobile (iOS)

Tags: css, html, controls, mobile-safari, html5-audio

The player renders fine in Firefox, IE and Chrome… in Safari mobile it is overflowing from its parent div and overlapping the first track in the playlist div below it. I don't have height set on any of the parent divs.

Here is the style I set for the controls:

```
[controls] {
width: 100%;
margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Shouldn't it be behaving like the other players by making enough room for its own height in the parent div?

Setting the controls to display: block didn't work. Adding wider margins above and below the player helps in iOS, but I would rather not have all the empty space there in other browsers.

- The player in iOS: http://i.imgur.com/vGxkQ6m.jpg
- In IE: http://i.imgur.com/iTqJXnK.jpg